# Hash Merge key variable has spaces

Tags: hash, merge, sas

I'm currently learning Hash merges and struggling a bit here.

First question would be when doing a hash merge which table should be hashed and which should be read in using the set statement? In the below example Tablex is on an SQL server and has a few million records. Table1 has 10% as many records as Tablex and is in my work temp folder.

I want to only select records from TableX which appear in Table1, would the code below be a good way of doing it? What would I do if I want to condition TableX as well with lets say where open date > '01 DEC 2010'd

Also is it possible to have a variable with spaces as the key variable or do I have to do the rename bit?

```
Data merges;
    if 0 then set server.Tablex(rename='account number'n= 
                  account_number_full2) table1;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash tab2(dataset:'table1');
                tab2.defineKey('Account_Number_full');
                tab2.defineData(all:'YES');
                tab2.defineDone();
    end;


    set Tablex(rename='account number'n= account_number_full2);


    if tab2.find(key:account_number_full2) = 0
    then output;
run;
```

Comment: Remember every record in the remote table will be transferred to SAS for evaluation.  The only way to reduce the 'transfer' is to upload `table1` to the server and perform a pass-through join in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

let us try to understand through an example. what you mention in set statement comes as output in this case have1 table. Your hash table is have. if *n* = 0 then set have1 is needed only for set table. You donot need *all* for hash table as you are not using that data for your final output table.

```
data have;
input id value $;
datalines;
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
;

data have1;
  input id date:mmddyy10.;
 format date mmddyy10.;
 datalines;
 2 01/15/2018
 3 01/01/2017
;

Data merges;
if 0 then set have1;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash tab2(dataset:'have');
            tab2.defineKey('id');
            tab2.defineDone();
end;


set have1;


if tab2.find(key:id) = 0
;
run;
```

if you want to include date you can do a where clause as dataset options as shown below.

```
    Data merges;
if 0 then set have1;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
 declare hash tab2(dataset:'have');
        tab2.defineKey('id');
        tab2.defineDone();
 end;


  set have1(where= (date gt '01JAN2018'd));


  if tab2.find(key:id) = 0;
  run;
```

Comment: Be careful with the double-set method. This will automatically retain all variables in `have1`.

Comment: if 0 then set have1; this only to read descriptor part for parameter matching

Comment: Correct; however, if you do this method with a hash left join, such as `rc = h.Find();`, all of the data columns associated with that hash variable will be retained until the next match. This can cause unexpected results. It is safer to initialize variables with length statements instead of using a double set statement.

Answer (score 0):

The variable **names** in a hash can contain any character only if the SAS session has turned on

```
option validvarname = any;
```

This option might be set if you are importing Excel data or have a data source that has columns not conforming to typical name naming conventions -- start with _ or letter, followed by any number of _, letter or digit.

When referencing the unusually named column in DATA step code you will have to use the SAS name-literal syntax (quoted reference followed by N), however, when passing the column name to the hash constructors (as a string) you will use the name and not the name-literal:

```
"<column-name>"N
```

Sample code:

```
options validvarname = any;

data have;
  "my key name is spacey"N = "key-1";  **** name-literal syntax used here;
  x = 123;
run;

data _null_;
  if 0 then set have; * prep pdv;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash h(dataset:'have');
    h.defineKey("my key name is spacey");  **** name with spaces passed here;
    h.defineData("x");
    h.defineDone();
  end;

  'my key name is spacey'N = "key-0";   **** name-literal used here;
  rc = h.find();
  put rc= x=;

  'my key name is spacey'N = "key-1";  **** name-literal used here;
  rc = h.find();
  put rc= x=;    
run;
```

As for the join.

- SET the remote table
- Apply `where` to the remote table.  The SQLSRV database engine will pass the criteria to the SQL and it will apply it prior to sending data over the 'wire' back to the DATA step.
- If the key variable name is the same in the tablex and the lookup, you can use the simpler `hash.find()`.  `hash.find(key:<expression>)` is only needed when names don't align, or the key in one domain must be transformed before becoming a suitable lookup (such as looking for a login match on password will only work after the entered-text is hashed and then compared to master login table)